# how to make svn repository on amazon EC2 ubuntu available for svn clients

Tags: svn, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am able to launch linux ami or ubuntu ami instance on amazon ec2. also able to setup subversion and create repository on it But when i am trying to access it via URL as public dns name provided by amazon ec2 instance into browser but its not showing anything.Even i am not getting any descent step by step guide or tutorial anywhere.Kindly help me or let me know any descent tutorial for setting up subversion repository on ec2 instance.Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to either [configure Apache HTTP Server to expose your repos via HTTP(S)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) or [configure `svnserve` for svn:// or svn+ssh:// scheme access](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html). See [SVNBook | Choosing a Server Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html).

Make sure to allow HTTP(S) or svn:// (port 3690, by default) traffic in ["Security Group"
settings of your Amazon EC2 machine](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/computebasics/getting-started-security-group.html).